# TypeScript combine type-aliases with inheritance and generics

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance, composition, type-alias

I have some deep inherited classes in my code combined with generics and composition. In many of the higher classes which uses services tailored for a combination of the same hierarchy I am forced to specify the full hierarchy for every type although it could be deduced from the types I already defined, this makes the code hard to read, hard to right and hard to maintain(when I want to switch a type I need to do it in all the places for example).

I was thinking about using type-definition in my files, but combined with generics and since it is defined out side of the class I am having a hard time achieving this.

Here is a minimized example of the issue:

```
export class BaseLine {
}

export class BaseHeader<TLines extends BaseLine> {
    lines: TLines[];
}

export class ServiceA
    <THeader extends BaseHeader<TLines>,
    TLines extends BaseLine> {
}

export class ServiceB
    <THeader extends BaseHeader<TLines>,
    TLines extends BaseLine> {
}

export class HeaderDetail 
    <THeader extends BaseHeader<TLines>,
    TLines extends BaseLine> {
    serviceA: ServiceA<THeader, TLines>;
    serviceB: ServiceB<THeader, TLines>;
}
```

Now imagine there are more than 2 generics types for a class, more than 2 services and I get a file which is half-full of types. Type-aliases could really make a difference here, what I would really want to do is something like:

```
type TLines = any extends BaseLine;
export class BaseHeader<TLines> {
    lines: TLines[];
}

type TLines = any extends BaseLine;
type THeader = any extends BaseHeader<TLines>;
export class ServiceA <THeader> {
}

type TLines = any extends BaseLine;
type THeader = any extends BaseHeader<TLines>;
export class Service <THeader> {
}

type TLines = any extends BaseLine;
type THeader = any extends BaseHeader<TLines>;
export class HeaderDetail <THeader> {
    serviceA: ServiceA<THeader>;
    serviceB: ServiceB<THeader>;
}
```

But, I can't find the right way to do it, the ts keeps giving we cryptic error: '?' expected, I am assuming it is since the extends syntax is not supposed to be used like that in type-aliases.

Is there a way to make type-aliases work like that?
Is there maybe a different maybe even better to do that? (without creating more types..)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make every variable in the chain be a generic.  Instead you can have one generic which refers to the highest object (`THeader` rather than `TLines`).

```
export class HeaderDetail <THeader extends BaseHeader<any>> {
}
```

If you want to access the type of `TLines`, you can get it by working backwards.

```
type HeaderLines<THeader> = THeader extends BaseHeader<infer TLines> ? TLines : never;
```

```
export class ServiceA <THeader extends BaseHeader<any>> {
    lines: HeaderLines<THeader>[];

    constructor( header: THeader ) {
        this.lines = header.lines;
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/aNnxqW)